# Count duplicate objects with different equalities in java

Tags: java

I'm lost on what Java 8 could do for counting duplicates using only 1 equals. I know the use of Map and Set but the problem is:

```
public class CustomObject{
  private int random_num;
  private String random_str;
}
```

```
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        CustomObject obj = (CustomObject) o;
        return Int.compare(obj.random_int, random_int) == 0 && Objects.equals(random_str, obj.random_str);
    }
```

I want to compare CustomObject by 2 ways.

1. Equal when they have the same `random_num` and the same `random_str`,
2. Equal when they only have the same `random_str`.

For (1), I would do implement equals and hash code for the `random_num` and `random_str` attributes, then use a Map or Set to count duplicates.

But for (2), I don't know if I can override equals to count duplicates using Map or Set again, or need to do it with a different approach. I want to count duplicates only if they have the same `random_str`.

Comment: if this all has to be done within the equals method, what is stopping you from using conditional statements within the equals?

Comment: Why not use a Map or Set of just the strings for the case where you want to dedupe `random_str`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean about dedupe, I believe if I've used Map or Set to compare random_num and random_str, when I use again Map or Set to compare only random_str, it won't work because I already set the equality of Object is when random_num and random_str are the same.

Comment: @Hpzz Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description where you need `equals()` to work with `random_num` and `random_str` and where you need `equals()` to work only with `random_str`.

Comment: Implement two [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) classes for your two compare strategies. E.g. in a [TreeMap constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-) you can then provide your own comparator.

Comment: "_when I use again Map or Set to compare only random_str, it won't work because I already set the equality of Object is when random_num and random_str are the same._" - If I understood correctly, I don't think this is possible in the order you described. By your own words, the second case is a subset of the first. The only way I see this possible is if you change the order of the comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you are aiming for duplicate count, and there are multiple ways to define "equalities". As it is not possible to have 2 `equals` in 1 class,
we can use Java `record` and `Collectors.groupingBy` can be handy tools in this case.

The benefit of using [`record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/language/records.html) as key are

1. `equals` and `hashcode` are automatically implemented
2. It is immutable.(which make it safe to be a key)

First we need create a record with the field we want for equalities

```java
record KeyWithFieldYouWant(Integer field1, String field2, ...){}
```

Then we can write group by

```java
Map<KeyWithFieldYouWant, Long> countPerKey = objectList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                customObject -> new KeyWithFieldYouWant(customObject.getField1(), customObject.getField2(), ...)
                , Collectors.counting()
        ));
```

To get the count for each key.

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to be case for Guava [Equivalence](https://guava.dev/releases/28.2-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) or Apache [Equator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/Equator.html) class. These classes are sometimes helpful if one needs custom equality logic. The `Equivalence` is related to natural `Object.equals` in similar way as `Comparator` is to `Comparable`.

You can also do the same without external libraries of course:

- create a two wrapper classes of `YourObject` (the naming `Object` is not well chosen), say, `WrapperByNum` and `WrapperByNumAndStr`
- implement `equals` and `hashCode` on wrapper classes using whatever fields of wrapped class you want
- use collections `Set<WrapperByNum>` etc., then extract original class using `set.stream().map(wrapperByNum -> wrapperByNum.getYourObject())....`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't know about wrapper classes.